# sum vectors values with cuda C++

Tags: cuda

I try to sum many vectors values using CUDA c++. I found some solution for two vectors. As you can see, just possible to add two vectors but I wanna generate vectors dynamically with the same length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// CUDA kernel. Each thread takes care of one element of c
 __global__ void vecAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n)
{
// Get our global thread ID
int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
// Make sure we do not go out of bounds
if (id < n)
    c[id] = a[id] + b[id];
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
// Size of vectors
int n = 100000;

// Host input vectors
double *h_a;
double *h_b;
//Host output vector
double *h_c;

// Device input vectors
double *d_a;
double *d_b;
//Device output vector
double *d_c;

// Size, in bytes, of each vector
size_t bytes = n*sizeof(double);

// Allocate memory for each vector on host
h_a = (double*)malloc(bytes);
h_b = (double*)malloc(bytes);
h_c = (double*)malloc(bytes);

// Allocate memory for each vector on GPU
cudaMalloc(&d_a, bytes);
cudaMalloc(&d_b, bytes);
cudaMalloc(&d_c, bytes);

int i;
// Initialize vectors on host
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    h_a[i] = sin(i)*sin(i);
    h_b[i] = cos(i)*cos(i);
}

// Copy host vectors to device
cudaMemcpy( d_a, h_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy( d_b, h_b, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

int blockSize, gridSize;

// Number of threads in each thread block
blockSize = 1024;

// Number of thread blocks in grid
gridSize = (int)ceil((float)n/blockSize);

// Execute the kernel
vecAdd<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, n);

// Copy array back to host
cudaMemcpy( h_c, d_c, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

// Sum up vector c and the print result divided by n, this should equal 1 
within error
double sum = 0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    sum += h_c[i];
printf("final result: %f\n", sum/n);

// Release device memory
cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);

// Release host memory
free(h_a);
free(h_b);
free(h_c);

return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this for many vectors? My vectors size are:

```
#vector length
N = 1000 
#number of vectors
i = 300000
v[i] = [1,2,..., N]
```

As result i need to get:

```
out[i]= [sum(v[1]), sum(v[2]),..., sum(v[i])]
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There is some confusion between the CUDA C++ example which you have given and what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to reduce each vector and store the individual sums (reduction) of all vectors into an array? **OR** Do you want to perform element-wise addition of all the vectors?

Comment: What does `sum(v)` mean? Is that a reduction operation? The code you have shown is vector addition, which isn't at all the same thing

Comment: as can clearly be seen from the above example, we can just add two vectors. I wanna to calculate the summation of N vectors. I mean we can generate vectors dynamically with the same length ( V = 300000 #number of vectors ). So I declare the number of vectors and program should give me the summation of all the vectors.

Comment: sum(v) that means the summation of all the vectors which we declare as a parameter

Comment: I'll gratefully appreciate if anyone helps me to achieve an appropriate result

Comment: Summation and addition are two different operations and it seems to me that you either don't understand the difference, or are unable to clearly describe what you want to do. Do you want `a[i] = b[i] + c[i] + d[i] + ... + z[i]` or do you want `a[i] = sum(j=1 to n){b[j]}`?

Comment: Think of your vectors, all of the same length, as the rows of a matrix.  It's unclear if you want a result that is the sum of the rows of that matrix (each row sum is an element of the vector result), or the sum of the columns of that matrix (each column sum  is an element of the vector result), or something else.  Regardless, there are various questions that deal with summing rows or columns of a matrix here on the `cuda` tag.  If you gave a complete host-code example of what you are trying to do, it would probably be clearer.

Comment: I'm  sorry if I can not explain clearly but I want a[i] = b[i] + c[i] + d[i] + ... + z[i] but I don't know how can I do that dynamically

Comment: that operation is a matrix column sum

Comment: I implemented with matrix Robert but is it possible to do it with vectors? I mean like this : a[i] = b[i] + c[i] + d[i] + ... + z[i]

Comment: You can do it with vectors, but somehow your kernel code will need to comprehend the number of vectors to be added (which is effectively the matrix approach, and would require a loop of some sort in your kernel code) or else you would need to call the vector add kernel multiple times.  I assume you can take the vector add code you have presented to call the kernel multiple times.  This will be much less efficient. The operation would be equivalent to: `a[i] = a[i] + b[i]`, `a[i] = a[i] + c[i]`, `a[i] = a[i] + d[i]`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing multiple vectors together in a fashion similar to the code you have shown (i.e. generating elementwise sums) is equivalent to summing the columns of a matrix.  And this idea represents a sensible way to realize the solution.

We will treat your vectors as a matrix, where each vector is a row in the matrix.  The CUDA kernel will assign one thread to each column, and will sum the elements of that column, producing a single number result.  That single number result will become one element of the vector result of the entire problem.

Here is a fully worked example demonstrating one possible approach:

```
$ cat t2.cu
#include <iostream>

typedef double mt;
const int nTPB = 64;

template <typename T>
__global__ void column_sum(T *matrix, T *sums, unsigned n_vectors, unsigned vector_length){

  unsigned idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < vector_length){
    T temp = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n_vectors; i++)
      temp += matrix[i*vector_length+idx];
    sums[idx] = temp;}
}

int main(){
  const unsigned vlen = 1000;
  const unsigned nvec = 300000;
  mt *h_matrix, *d_matrix, *h_sums, *d_sums;
  // create the desired number of vectors as a single matrix
  h_sums = new mt[vlen];
  h_matrix = new mt[vlen*nvec];
  cudaMalloc(&d_matrix, vlen*nvec*sizeof(mt));
  cudaMalloc(&d_sums, vlen*sizeof(mt));
  size_t count = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < nvec; i++)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < vlen; j++)
      h_matrix[count++] = j;
  cudaMemcpy(d_matrix, h_matrix, vlen*nvec*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  column_sum<<<(vlen+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(d_matrix, d_sums, nvec, vlen);
  cudaMemcpy(h_sums, d_sums, vlen*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < vlen; i++) if (h_sums[i] != ((mt)nvec)*i) {std::cout << " mismatch at " << i << " was: " << h_sums[i] << " should be: " << ((mt)nvec)*i << std::endl; return -1;}
  std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t2 t2.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t2
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
no error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that this methodology only creates as many threads on the GPU as there are vector elements (1000 in the above example).  1000 threads would be enough to keep only the smallest GPUs busy.  However this algorithm will be efficient on most GPUs if your vector length is 10,000 or longer.   If you'd like to explore creating more efficient algorithms for small problem sizes, you can study the idea of a [classical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).